# MySQL server has gone away - Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=72

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I tried to use php to connect to a MySQL sever running on another computer on the same network.
Server IP: 192.168.0.111
My IP: 192.168.0.109
I am currently using XAMPP which I just upgraded to version 8.0.0. After the upgrade, I got a few errors on my screen:

Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=72 in C:\xampp\htdocs\submit.php on line 95
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=28684 in C:\xampp\htdocs\submit.php on line 95
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\submit.php on line 95
Connection failed: MySQL server has gone away

MySQL server is running on the default port 3306 and here are the latest logs:
2020-12-27 16:11:21 29 [Warning] IP address '192.168.0.109' has been resolved to the host name '192.168.0.109', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
2020-12-27 16:11:21 29 [Warning] Aborted connection 29 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '192.168.0.109' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

The server is not using any password at the moment.

What can I do to fix this issue?
Thanks.

[update] I see no errors when I use server name as 'localhost' when the php file is on the MySQL server.

Comment: Are you sure there is a MySQL instance running with its port open? You could try to use [Nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) to scan ports of server IP. `nmap -T4 -v -A -F 192.168.0.111` should suffice.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the MySQL server is running with the port open.

Comment: Make sure that you have a sufficient value in the `wait_timeout` setting, The default value for this setting is 8 hours (28800) seconds. But if it's set lower (like seconds), it could be that your connection is being terminated before the SQL command is executed

Comment: Thanks for your response. I restarted the server and it seems to work now without any issues.